# I am confused to make mlmodel updatable using coreml3 tools

Tags: coreml, cross-entropy, coremltools, mlmodel

I have a regressor mlmodel trained using mobilenetv2。The last several layers are as follows:

[image]

I wanna to make this mlmodel to a updatable mlmodel and train the innerProduct layer (fully-connected layer in pytorch). I have converted the mlmodel referencing to this blog:
https://machinethink.net/blog/coreml-training-part4/ . But I found that the updatable mlmodel's second training input is default set to "score_true" and it is just a value(datatype: int32).

[image]

However, the output of softmax layer is a vector with 10 float values. So how can I set the second training input to a vector, because the ground truth is a vector with 10 float values.

And I look up the API of CrossEntropyLoss int coremltools3.3. Its input param can accept a vector of length N. So how can I change the default generated score_true from a intVal to a vector?
Thanks very much.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you pass into the `score_true` MLMultiArray is the index of the class. You don't need to one-hot encode this yourself, i.e. no need to turn it into a vector of length N.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The model I used is not a classification model. The softmax layer's output is a vector of length 10, such as (0, 0, 0.1, 0.3, **0.5**, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ). Then the vector is used to calc the Weighted Arithmetic Mean with (1, 2, 3, 4, **5**, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10). So I cannot just set "**score_true = 5**" , which 5 is the index of max prob val 0.5.  I have to set the ground truth value as a vector.

Comment: So is (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) the vector you want to pass in, or am I not understanding this? If you want the target to be a vector you should change the shape and datatype of the `score_true` training input by hand (using coremltools).